# Linearsort - runtime analysis

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

First of all, thanks a lot to everyone who posted in my question topics, you have all helped me a lot and it was really fun, both to ask and read your answers, and improve my work.

...................

Depended on `n` and `m`, what will be the runtime of the following algorithm?
I don't know the value of `n` or `m` so I will just say it is very big :)
However, I don't quite understand what "<--" stands for which is a big problem to solve the task.

But I gave it a try:
When we say `n` is something very big, then the entire array `arr` will be very big. So far we got a runtime `O(n)`, this will be required to run through the array `arr`, same applied for the other arrays, so we are still at `O(n)`. Each `for` loop will also cost `O(n)` so we will end up with `O(n+x)` where x is a big integer, as big as the array `arr` size.
You can see I have skipped the parts that got "<--" because I really don't know how to understand it. 
But yeah the total runtime will be `O(n)` in my opinion, is that correct?

```
Input: Array arr with n integers, from 1 to m
Output: Array arr sorted upwards

Initialize Array B with length m which is set to 0 everywhere
n <-- |arr|
Initialize Array C with length n
for i = 1 to n do
   B[arr[i] <-- B[arr[i]] + 1
end for
for j = 2 to m do
   B[j] <-- B[j] + B[j-1]
end for
for i = n down to 1 do
   C[B[arr[i]]] <-- arr[i]
   B[arr[i]] <-- B[arr[i]] - 1
end for
return C
```

Comment: `<--` is assignment and this algorithm is counting sort

Comment: Thank you! I first thought this was Insertionsort but then realized here are no for loops within for loops :D

Answer (score 1):

so the run time of the algorithm is O(2*n+m) => O(n+m) so it is linear

Comment: O(2*n+m), why exactly 2*n? I think because of the array arr and "Initialize Array C with length n", right?

Comment: you have 2 times a for loop which goes from 1 to n (or n to 1) so you have 2*n... but 2* is a stable factor, so you can ignore it and count it as O(n)

Comment: @itaminul - if m is considered to be a constant, then time complexity would be O(n) as constants are ignored.